# How swagger's response schema's code matches node.js' response status code?

Tags: node.js, swagger

I'm new to swagger. I want to use the Online Swagger Editor to test some examples. But I suffered the problem as the image[
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrRjG.png)].

The following is my design in the Swagger Editor:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: API example
  description: An API example to pratice.
schemes:
      - https
      - http
    host: '127.0.0.1:3000'
    basePath: /users
    paths:
      /connect:
        get:
          summary: get some infos!
          description: get some info!
          responses:
            '200':
              description: haha success!
            '404':
              description: not found!
            default:
              description: error!!!!
```

And my node.js code are as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/connect', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("111");
  res.send('200');
});

module.exports = router;
```

I don't know how the node.js return the code like '200' and '404'.

Can someone handle it? Thanks so much for answer my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in nodejs use the function res.status()

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/connect', function(req, res, next) {
    modelUser.findAll().then(function (data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            res.status(200).send({success: true, data: data});
        } else {
            res.status(404).send({success: false, message: "some message"});
       }
    });
});
```

swagger example in YAML format:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: EXAMPLE
  description: Documentation ......
  version: 1.0.0
  contact:
    email: richych92@gmail.com
schemes:
  - http
host: '192.168.1.55:8280'
basePath: /fojalAcademia/v1
tags:
  - name: Conect
    description: resources user......
paths:
  /conect:
    get:
      tags:
        - Conect
      summary: users list
      description: retun users array
      produces:
        - application/json
      responses:
        '200':
          description: data succes
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/resUsersSuccess'
        '404':
          description: data error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/resUserError'

definitions:
  resUsersSuccess:
    type: object
    properties:
      success:
        type: boolean
        description: true or false..in this case true
      data:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/dataUser'
  dataUser:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
        description: user id
      email:
        type: string
        description: user email
      edad:
        type: integer
        format: int64
        description: user´s age

  resUserError:
    type: object
    properties:
      success:
        type: boolean
        description: true or false..in this case false
      message:
        type: string
        description: error message
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks a lot!